# Object Variable Not Set when Closing UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm experiencing the error `Object variable or With block variable not set` error when a userform (`UF_Main`) within my Excel 2007 project is unloaded either by clicking the red X or following a `Unload Me` statement.

I've managed to isolate the error down to the following code which is in a Module:

```
Public Sub fProgressExit()

intProVol = 0
intProStep = 0
Unload UF_Progress
UF_Main.Show 'This line is causing the error'

End Sub
```

Removing the line prevents the error from occurring.

When the userform `UF_Main` is unloaded, there's no reference to the procedure above and the userform that the procedure relates to (`UF_Progress`) is already unloaded.

Why do I receive the error when `fProgressExit` isn't executed when the userform closes?

Comment: Probably UF_Main, depending on the references structure of your project, is unloaded together with UF_Progress so it cannot be shown. If your need is to make UF_Progress disappear before UF_Main is shown, try UF_Progress.Hide first and unload it later.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Thanks, I've just tried hiding the userform rather than unloading but it still throws the error.

Comment: Instead of chaining Forms, use a supervisory routine in a standard module (for example) to manage the forms. Declare them properly using the pattern `Dim ufM as UF_Main: set ufM = New UF_Main: ufM.Show`. That way you have a reference to the Forms and full control over their life cycle.

Comment: Could you please add a watcher to UF_Main and tell us what it is just before executing the Show method?

Comment: Try to add a Is-Nothing check before you call the Show method, something like: If Not UF_Main Is Nothing Then UF_Main.Show End If.

Comment: the code that launchs fProgressExit must be in userform_terminate and NOT in userform_Query_close . The last one is called before the userform is closed, and the 1rst after it's closed. you are trying to show UF_Main when it's already shown.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want the form to close , you can use  `UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)` 's properties :

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer) 'before unloaded
Select Case CloseMode
    Case 0: 'Close initiated by the little [X] button top right of the UserForm
        'To prevent closing this way : cancel=true
    Case 1: 'close initiated by Unload UserForm
    Case 2, 3: 'close initiated by windows(2) / Task manager(3)
End Select
End Sub
```

Note that : `UserForm_QueryClose' is activated before the Form closes,`
UserForm_Terminate` is activated After the Form is already closed+Unloaded.